# Arrange columns of two different grids with gaps in line

Tags: html, css, css-grid

How do I get the two grid cells "right" and "col" in a line below each other without adjusting the HTML?
Without gaps this is not a problem, but as soon as gaps are added, the columns are no longer in line.

```css
*, *::before, *::after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.OuterContainer {
  display: grid;
  column-gap: 32px;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 3fr;
}

.Col4Grid {
    display: grid;
    column-gap: 32px;
    grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr;
}


.Col {
  background-color: #e7e7e7;
}
```

```html
<div class="OuterContainer">
  <div class="Col">
    left
  </div>
  <div class="Col">
    right
  </div>
</div>

<div class="Col4Grid">
  <div class="Col">col</div>
  <div class="Col">col</div>
  <div class="Col">col</div>
  <div class="Col">col</div>
</div>
```

Comment: can you please add a drawing of the intended layout? I have troubles to get a picture of what you're describing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I hope I got your intended layout correct. Just apply the same grid-column rule to both containers. then let the column (right)  span 3 columns with: `grid-column: span 3;`

```css
*, *::before, *::after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.OuterContainer,
.Col4Grid {
  display: grid;
  column-gap: 32px;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(4, 1fr);
}

.Col {
  background-color: #e7e7e7;
}

.OuterContainer .Col:nth-child(2) {
  grid-column: span 3;
}
```

```html
<div class="OuterContainer">
  <div class="Col">
    left
  </div>
  <div class="Col">
    right
  </div>
</div>

<div class="Col4Grid">
  <div class="Col">col</div>
  <div class="Col">col</div>
  <div class="Col">col</div>
  <div class="Col">col</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Exactly what i searched for! Thanks alot!

Answer (score 1):

Another more "dirty math" result. Just change the variable to whatever size you need.

```css
*,
*::before,
*::after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

:root {
 --g-gap: 40px;
}

.OuterContainer {
  display: grid;
  column-gap: var(--g-gap);
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 3fr;
}

.Col4Grid {
  display: grid;
  column-gap: var(--g-gap);
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr;
}

.Col {
  background-color: #e7e7e7;
}

.Col4Grid .Col:first-child {
width: calc(100% + 1/2*var(--g-gap));
}

.Col4Grid .Col:not(:first-child) {
margin-left: calc(1/2*var(--g-gap));
}
```

```html
<div class="OuterContainer">
  <div class="Col">
    left
  </div>
  <div class="Col">
    right
  </div>
</div>

<div class="Col4Grid">
  <div class="Col">col</div>
  <div class="Col">col</div>
  <div class="Col">col</div>
  <div class="Col">col</div>
</div>
```

This is of course not responsive (if you intend to use 100+px) and definitely not a good way to solve this, but I thought it is a funny way to tweak things!

Comment: far to complicated to uses dozens of properties to calculate the correct spacings. Easier to use my solution which does not require to use math nor to use multiple proeprties.